# Can one abbreviate the Spanish given name José María to José Mª in English, like in Spanish?

Tags: abbreviations, translation, symbols

According to the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa),

> José María (abbreviated José Mª) is a Spanish language male given name, usually considered a single given name rather than two names[.]

[Related, possibly helpful, but ignorable, questions to the title question:] Is the symbol (?) 'ª' even recognised in English? Do otherwise Spanish-speaking North-Americans use it, *also in English*?

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that most Portuguese (and as such I presume Spanish) keyboards have superscript letters readily available. In English, there are only awkward shortcuts.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I'm not even sure if this is the symbol ª or the superscript a. (Although, you also see them underlined in Spain, which suggests it is a symbol.) According to Wikipedia (elsewhere) they are _not_ to be confused.

Comment: In a statement such as yours, explaining the usage, it's acceptable; whether it should be classified as 'English' is debatable (but surely ignorable, if you say so). I certainly wouldn't use it without explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't use it. Native English speakers won't know what it means even though abbreviations such as J<sup>as</sup> (James) were common in the past.

Comment: See: “[Ordinal Indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator)” (*Wikipedia*).

Comment: [Some people do](http://city-lines.com/jose-m-subero-english/) use the abbreviation in English. However, most English speakers are likely unfamiliar with it. (Actually, I can't find any reference to it in my Spanish textbook. It does cover the ordinals, however.)

Comment: Thanks for this. My Great Grandfather (Spanish) was specified as José Mª. Now I know what it means!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So-called "superscript contractions" used to be a common practice in English, when handwriting was much more common, but it is now considered obsolete. 
[This Cambridge course](https://www.english.cam.ac.uk/ceres/ehoc/conventions.html#contractions) on early Modern English handwriting gives the following advice to students:

> superscript characters, often a form of contraction which may imply preceding omitted characters, as in w<sup>ch</sup> for 'which'. Other common contractions of this type include y<sup>r</sup> for 'your' or 'yowr'; S<sup>r</sup> for 'Sir' and M<sup>r</sup> for 'Master'; w<sup>t</sup> or w<sup>th</sup> for 'with' (and wthout for 'without'); ma<sup>ty</sup> for 'maiesty' or ma<sup>ties</sup> for 'maiesties'; and words ending in -m<sup>t</sup> for '-ment', such as gouernem<sup>t</sup> for 'gouernement' or parliam<sup>t</sup> for 'parliament'.

Wikipedia glosses over this practice, giving nothing useful to quote.

This practice also extended to personal names, for example **J <sup>os</sup>** for Joseph or **W<sup>m</sup>** for William.  The following excerpt from [an 1877 land atlas](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/32594/p.52-53%20-%20Ninth%20District.JPG?sequence=16) contains at least  3 examples that I can see:

[image: map snippet with superscript contractions]

It was mostly an artifact of handwriting, occasionally printed, but fell out of use with automated typesetting. Nowadays you see them in only a few places such as  ordinals (1<sup>st</sup> , 2<sup>nd</sup> , 3<sup>rd</sup> ) and special symbols such as the Trademark<sup>TM</sup>  symbol.

So to actually answer your question, a few people might recognize what you're trying to do, but they would find it odd or contrived. The rest would just be confused.

Answer (score 0):

In English, there are slang names for full names, such as Bob/Robert, Bill/William, Dick/Richard, Jim/James, Joe/Joseph, Tim/Timothy, Chris/Christopher, Ron/Ronald, Ted or Teddy/Edward, Tony/Anthony, Dave/David, etc.

Other than that, we use the full name, and would defer to other languages' naming conventions.

People though, unless they know Spanish naming conventions, wouldn't know what that means, so you'll have to clarify that beforehand to your audience.

Comment: This isn't about familiar diminutives of names, but a purely orthographic abbreviation. The difference is that _Bob_, _Ted_, and similar names are pronounced varieties committed to writing; _José Mª_ is read out loud as _José María_ just like _mr._ is read out loud as _mister_.

Comment: And this wouldn't translate to English speakers.