# What does this symbol from Revolutionary War rolls mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations, symbols

[image]

We are transcribing Continental Army rolls & encountered this symbol numerous times. It really appears to mean "ditto" as in the "Rank" column, we'll see 'Private' with the next 4-5 entires below showing this symbol.

I've searched online but can't confirm. Can anyone help?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark) for ***ditto*** says *The abbreviation **do.** is also used [see above],* where "see above" refers to a facsimile of "an advertisement from 1833" where the abbreviation is used repeatedly. (So I'm closevoting for lack of prior research.)

Comment: The abbreviation _do._ is rare in current English, but it remains quite common in some other languages.

Comment: This is related to [this other EL&U question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353447/can-one-abbreviate-the-spanish-given-name-josé-maría-to-josé-mª-in-english-like/353589#353589) that appeared last, week, dealing with 'superscript contractions' which are now considered obsolete in English. **d<sup><u>o</u></sup>** eventually morphed into a symbol just like a double quote (**"**)

Comment: Well it looks like a 'd' and an 'o' which are the first and last letters of 'ditto'. It is similar to the numero symbol, №, which combines the first and last letters of 'numero'.

Comment: I think the evidence for the symbol meaning ditto is solid & clearly meets the context of the list in question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have transcribed hundreds of letters from mostly the 19th Century and find it a common practice to include the last letter of the word, usually as a superscript and often underlined.